# Xen 4.0.1 vifname gone from config file?

Tags: networking, xen

Playing around with xen 4.0.1, trying to setup a simple domU.

When I put the parameter in vif like :

```
vif = [ 'ip=192.168.1.41,mac=00:16:3E:2F:F4:78,bridge=xenbr0,vifname=domu1' ]
```

It fails

```
error: Device 0 (vif) could not be connected. 
ip link set vif5.0 name domu1 failed
```

Also, running the command from dom0:

```
ip link set vif5.0 name domu1
```

returns

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the `vifname=` command isn't properly supported in many versions of Xen.

My guess is that you can only rename the device before certain usage and the Xen vif scripts are doing it too late.

Looking at the source in `vif-common.sh`:

```
vifname=$(xenstore_read_default "$XENBUS_PATH/vifname" "")
if [ "$vifname" ]
then
  if [ "$command" == "online" ] && ! ip link show "$vifname" >&/dev/null
  then
    do_or_die ip link set "$vif" name "$vifname"
  fi
  vif="$vifname"
fi
```

I don't see any obvious bugs. You should look at your `vif-common.sh` and confirm that it is the same as this.

**Edit**: I think maybe the vifX.Y interface may not be up at this point. Try commenting out the `do_or_die` line. That should set `vif="$vifname"` and if the device is then created later there is no reason to rename it.

Comment: Yes, the same; it's the 'ip link set vif5.0 name domu1' which fails. Any guess on a 'bug' of ip command ?

Answer (score 1):

Your link vif5.0 is used...

This solution function very well. Every time I suggest you do not use it on a production server ...

```
*** scripts/vif-common.sh.old   2012-03-28 16:00:50.555630500 +0200
--- scripts/vif-common.sh       2012-03-28 15:59:58.775633091 +0200
***************
*** 70,88 ****
--- 70,90 ----
      # Check presence of compulsory args.
      XENBUS_PATH="${XENBUS_PATH:?}"
      dev="${dev:?}"

      vifname=$(xenstore_read_default "$XENBUS_PATH/vifname" "")
      if [ "$vifname" ]
      then
          if [ "$command" == "online" ] && ! ip link show "$vifname" >&/dev/null
          then
+             ip link set "$dev" down
              do_or_die ip link set "$dev" name "$vifname"
+             ip link set "$vifname" up
          fi
          dev="$vifname"
      fi
  elif [ "$type_if" = tap ]; then
      # Check presence of compulsory args.
      : ${INTERFACE:?}

      # Get xenbus_path from device name.
      # The name is built like that: "tap${domid}.${devid}".
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one reason why this problem occurs:

```
ps auxw | grep -v grep | grep NetworkManager && service network-manager stop
```

`xm create` ... and good luck!

Solutions 1, 2 or 3:

1. dpkg - purge network-manager
2. service network-manager stop
3. man NetworkManager.conf and search 'unmanaged-devices ...

Explanation: http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889

Comment: Works on ubuntu 16.04, xen v4.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3 implemented:

Update NetworkManager.conf with:

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vif*
```