# Is is possible to use static VIFs on Xen?

Tags: xen, xenserver

Is it possible to use Static VIF names for virtual nics in Xen? Which don´t change on reboot of the VM?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Use `vif=<nicname>`, and maybe `mac=<mac_address>` in your *.cfg file.

```
vif  = [ 'bridge=xenbr0,vifname=resolver1.0,mac=00:16:3e:01:00:02', ]
```

There have to be similar option for libvirt and xend managed domUs.

Comment: Is this also possible with XenServer? I suppose yes, as they use exactly the same open source kernel, just add some GUI tools and some extras to it. But maybe someone can confirm this. Im fine with the auto generated MAC, I just want a specific VM not to change its vif device ID on each reboot which changes as each domain ID changes this is very annoying and I hate it as you cannot keep a specific VIF card and lose it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If Dom0 is using NetworkManager, see workaround to an issue using vifname here...

[Xen 4.0.1 vifname gone from config file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/223710/xen-4-0-1-vifname-gone-from-config-file/865953#865953)